# MLE bootstrap on poisson distribution

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, poisson, statistics-bootstrap

I have the following `Poisson` distribution:

```
Data
3 5 3 1 2 1 2 1 0 2 4 3 1 4 1 2 2 0 4 2 2 4 0 2 1 0 5 2 0 1 
2 1 3 0 2 1 1 2 2 0 3 2 1 1 2 2 5 0 4 3 1 2 3 0 0 0 2 1 2 2 
3 2 4 4 2 1 4 3 2 0 3 1 2 1 3 2 6 0 3 5 1 3 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 
1 0 3 1 2 3 3 3 2 1 1 2 3 0 0 1 5 1 1 3 1 2 2 1 0 3 1 0 1 1
```

I used the following code to find the MLE Θ̂

```
lik<-function(lam) prod(dpois(data,lambda=lam)) #likelihood function
nlik<- function(lam) -lik(lam) #negative-likelihood function
optim(par=1, nlik)
```

What I want to do is create a bootstrap confidence interval to test the null hypothesis that Θ = 1 at level 0.05 and find the p-value using the numerical optimization that I used above. 
I thought it would be something along the lines of this

```
n<-length(data)
nboot<-1000
boot.xbar <- rep(NA, nboot)
for (i in 1:nboot) {
data.star <- data[sample(1:n,replace=TRUE)]
boot.xbar[i]<-mean(data.star)
}
quantile(boot.xbar,c(0.025,0.975))
```

But I don't think this utilizes the optimization, and I am not sure how to get the p-value.

Answer (score 3):

A few points:

(1) For numerical stability you may like to consider negative log likelihood instead of negative likelihood.

(2) As per Zheyuan's suggestion, you need to use *optimize* in stead of *optim* for nll minimization in the 1-D parameter space.

```
lik<-function(lam) sum(log(dpois(data,lambda=lam))) #log likelihood function
nlik<- function(lam) -lik(lam) #negative-log-likelihood function
optimize(nlik, c(0.1, 2), tol = 0.0001)

# $minimum
# [1] 1.816661    
# $objective
# [1] 201.1172

n<-length(data)
nboot<-1000
boot.xbar <- rep(NA, nboot)
for (i in 1:nboot) {
  data.star <- data[sample(1:n,replace=TRUE)]
  boot.xbar[i]<-mean(data.star)
}
quantile(boot.xbar,c(0.025,0.975))
#  2.5%    97.5% 
# 1.575000 2.066667
```

(3) You may use mle2 from bbmle package to compute the MLE and construct the confidence intervals at once.

```
library(bbmle)
res <- mle2(minuslogl = nlik, start = list(lam = 0.1))
res   
# Coefficients:
#     lam 
# 1.816708     
# Log-likelihood: -201.12 

confint(profile(res)) # confint w.r.t. the likelihood profile
# 2.5 %   97.5 % 
# 1.586083 2.068626 

confint(res, method="uniroot") # based on root-finding to find the exact point where the profile crosses the critical level     
#    2.5 %   97.5 % 
# 1.586062 2.068606
```